# Django: 'ImproperlyConfigured at' after form POST using CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-urls

I want to add data to my database from form (which is CreateView). Unfortunately after posting I got

*'ImproperlyConfigured at/persons/new/'*

I was trying to edit my *urls.py*, but I think I missed something.

My **views.py**

```
class PersonListView(ListView):
    model = Person
    template_name = 'app/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'

class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['name','surname']
```

My **urls.py** in project

```
*imports*
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/',admin.site.urls),
    path('persons/', include('app.urls')),
]
```

My **urls.py** in app

```
*imports*
urlpatterns = [
    path('',PersonListView.as_view(),name='persons),
    path('new/',PersonCreateView.as_view(),name='person-create),
]
```

After submit my form, data are added to database but I got error like above.

Comment: You are missing a `success_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Short answer**: you should specify a [**`success_url`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.success_url) attribute in your view, or override [**`form_valid`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid).

In a [**`CreateView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.CreateView.object) (well most views with a [**`FormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin)), you need to specify what needs to happen when the form has been processed succesfully.

By default a [**`ModelFormMixin`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin) will first [save the object [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L123):

> ```
> def form_valid(self, form):
>     """If the form is valid, save the associated model."""
>     self.object = form.save()
>     return super().form_valid(form)
> ```

and then the underlying `FormMixin` will [redirect to the `success_url` [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L55):

> ```
> def form_valid(self, form):
>     """If the form is valid, redirect to the supplied URL."""
>     return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
> ```

The [`get_success_url` will retrieve the `success_url` attribute [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/views/generic/edit.py#L49), and raise, as you noticed, an `ImproperlyConfigured` error if that one is missing:

> ```
> def get_success_url(self):
>     """Return the URL to redirect to after processing a valid form."""
>     if not self.success_url:
>         raise ImproperlyConfigured("No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")
>     return str(self.success_url)  # success_url may be lazy
> ```

In you view, you thus can specify a `success_url`, for example with [**`reverse_lazy`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy):

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

class PersonCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Person
    fields = ['name','surname']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('persons')
```

Here `persons` is the *name* of the `path(..)` to which we redirect. Redirecting is typically the preferred way to handle a successful form: it is part of the [*Post/Redirect/Get* architectural pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). If you would render a page for the POST request, then a user that refreshes the page on the browser, will *resend* the same data to the server, and thus might actually create a *second* object.

Another option is to override `form_valid`, and do something else *after* calling the `super().form_valid(form)` (since that will save the object to the database).